# Using Google map Javascript API

Tags: javascript, web

I am creating a website that helps people locate a particular type of business i am trying to use google place map api . i don't know how to implement it even after reading the documentation, i want to achieve a website that has two text box one for the type of business and the other for the location whereby the map will display the location of different business specify in the first inputbox

Comment: please post what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

**this is what i have done so far**

```js
  // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
      // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
      // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">
      
        var input = document.getElementById('input');
      var map;
      var infowindow;
      

      function initMap() {
        var pyrmont = {lat: 6.62714, lng: 3.33680};


        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: pyrmont,
          zoom: 15
        });

        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        service.nearbySearch({
          location: pyrmont,
          radius: 1000,
          type: [input]
        }, callback);
      }

      function callback(results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            createMarker(results[i]);
          }
        }
      }

      function createMarker(place) {
        var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: place.geometry.location
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.setContent(place.name);
          infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
      }
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" id="input" placeholder="enter type" width="100">
    <div id="map"></div>

 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=RUzLkDHpkqxRYJl7xxHR0UE&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```